# Package name does not correspond to blank file path

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 2.3.3, I get the following error in the java source files:

> Package name 'com.foo.bar' does not correspond to the file path ''

Note the *blank* filepath in the error, which I believe differences this from possible duplicate questions about package names vs file paths.  This seems like something more than just the package statement is damaged.

Assuming I know the top level directory on my own hard drive where this is installed (i.e., I know where StudioProjects is and have verified that they are there) how do I go about repairing this... or at least figure out what the correct package statement is?

**Update:**  Note that the manifest file *does* have a "package" tag, the contents of which I can copied directly into the package statements in the Java source files.  They were identical what was there before so the error persists.

Comment: is your project directory structure correct, i.e. src/main/java/com/foo/bar (with emphasis on the .../com/foo/bar).

Comment: @Les unlikely.  All the java files are in src/main/java  and that's that.  Possiby why the matching string is blank.  But it's not obvious to me exactly what this should look like in terms of directory structures or package statements.  Assume a toy project where all java files can safely reside in one directory with no intent to publish.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem was caused by having the java source files in the directory:

> src/main/java

Rather than the directory:

> src/main/java/com/foo/bar

This means that the package statements were pointing to an erroneous location (successfully detected) and the only reasonable place they could exist was expressed by an empty string (correctly reported but confusing.)

The simple solution was to create a new folder (technically a new package) called foo using the tools within Android Studio, relocating the source files there, and changing the package files to

> src/main/java/foo/
>
> package foo;

Android Studio assisted with refactoring, although it missed a few locations.